# Get file path from NSBundle in Swift

Tags: swift, file, nsbundle

I have a file stored in:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/083EA15E7/Documents/myFile.zip
```

It got there after I downloaded it from a server.

If I know the file name is `myFile.zip`, how can I find it with `NSBundle`?

Like this:

```
if let URL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myFile", withExtension: "zip") {
    // do stuff
}
```

currently this returns false, not sure how I can specify the whole path. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

This item is not in your bundle, an item in your bundle is something that you add before compiling, such as assets, fonts etc.

iOS provides each app with a sandbox. In that sandbox, the Documents folder exists. To access files from the Documents folder try this:

```
let documentsURL = NSURL(
  fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first!,
  isDirectory: true
)
```

To get the file, you will need to get its path and append it to the documents path like so.

```
let URLToMyFile = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyFile.zip")
```

To get the path as a string you can access the path property of the URL.

```
print(URLToMyPath.path!)
```

That will print out the path of your downloaded resource.

Comment: objective c equavalent?? plz??

Answer (score 3):

Tested on: **xCode 8.3.2** & **Swift 3.1**

First drag your file (JPG, MP3, ZIP) inside your project folder and make sure **Copy items if needed** is checked and project/app is selected in **Add to targets**[image]

Inside relevant **ViewController**

```
let fileName = "fileName"
let fileType = "fileType"

if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType) {
    print(filePath)
}
```

If you need to get the file URL you can use NSBundle method

```
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileType) {
    print(fileURL)
}
```

Also NSBundle method pathForResource has an initializer that you can specify in which directory your files are located like:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileType, inDirectory: "filesSubDirectory") {
    print(filePath)
}
```

And for getting file URL:

```
if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileType, subdirectory: "filesSubDirectory") {
    print(fileURL)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

run time created file are stored in Document directory not in NSBundle. NSBundle stores the files like System file you put in your Xcode project while your developing

Here is the example

> This code is fully tested on Swift 2.0

```
let file = "myFile.zip"
        if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
           //path will be stored here
            let sPath = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

      print(sPath) //  printing the file path

        }
```